# I need to call the page render after POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I submit a request to the server and then want to get the result without reloading the page (SPA principle), how can this be done using useEffect()?

```
I tried to do something like this:
useEffect (() => {
addProduct ();
})
```

but it's was a bad idea

```
import React,  {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import api from './api';

const HandleProduct = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('');

  const updateName = (e) =>{
    setName(e.target.value);
  }
  const updateDescription = (e) =>{
    setDescription(e.target.value);
  }
  const addProduct = () =>{
    const product = {
      name: name,
      description: description
    }
    api.addProduct(product)
    .then((req, res) =>{
      console.log(res);
    })
  }
return (
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={addProduct}>
            <input type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={updateName}/>
            <input type="text" name="description" value={description} onChange={updateDescription}/>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  );
}
export default HandleProduct;
```

Comment: After the post request, you will get new information from that request. What will be that data? The product? Where are you displaying the product? Where is that "name" that is the value for the input, coming from?

Comment: Data is the list of products, name  coming from express server

Comment: Sorry, but there's a piece of the puzzle that still does not fit, where are you going to display that list of products?

Comment: Please, pay attention to the new code, maybe it will give you the opportunity to understand what I want to do with my code

Answer (score 0):

When the callback with response is called you've got the repsonse with all data sent from API. Let's assume you want to get ID. I will add new hook for storing ID, setting it after POST method is completed, and displaying it.

```
  const [productId, setProductId] = useState(null);
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('');

  const updateName = (e) =>{
    setName(e.target.value);
  }
  const updateDescription = (e) =>{
    setDescription(e.target.value);
  }

    onSubmit() {
        const product = {
          name: name,
          description: description
        }
        api.addProduct(product)
        .then((req, res) =>{
          setProudctId(JSON.parse(res).id);
        })
      }


return (
    <div>

        {productId && <span>Your productId: {productId} </span>} 

        <form onSubmit={addProduct}>
            <input type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={updateName}/>
            <input type="text" name="description" value={description} onChange={updateDescription}/>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  );
}
export default HandleProduct;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems legit, yet, given that is not working, I'll give you another option to do it.

In App.js

```
<Router >
            <ProductsProvider>
              <Route exact path="/products" component={ProductsList} props={...props} />
              <Route exact path={'/products/add'} component={HandleProduct} 
props={...props} />
            </ProductsProvider>
          </Router>
```

In HandleProduct.js

```
import React,  {useState} from 'react';
import api from './api';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'

const HandleProduct = ({history}) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('');

  const updateName = (e) =>{
    setName(e.target.value);
  }
  const updateDescription = (e) =>{
    setDescription(e.target.value);
  }
  const addProduct = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const product = {
      name: name,
      description: description
    }
    api.addProduct(product)
    .then((req, res) =>{
      history.push('/products');
    })
  }

return (
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={addProduct}>
            <input type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={updateName}/>
            <input type="text" name="description" value={description} onChange={updateDescription}/>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you, but page products didn't re-render after i added new product, it is main goal

Comment: that is the item is added, but it only appears after manually reloading the page

Comment: I need you to provide the code of the component ProductsList

Comment: I provided the code, please see. thank you very much for your desire to help

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {ProductsContext} from './ProductsContext';

const ProductsList = () => {
  const [data] = useContext(ProductsContext);
  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(data)}
        {data.products.map((product, index)=>(
            <div key={index}>
                <p>{product.name}</p>
                <p><i>{product.description}</i></p>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
export default ProductsList;
```

Comment: This is getting messy. Can you please edit the ORGINAL QUESTION, with your UPDATED QUESTION please? I don't know what to look for precisely and it's not gonna be useful for anyone else apart from you if you don't make very clear what do you need in your question. Thanks